# NavigationItem right button not setting

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am losing my mind setting the right button on my custom Navigation Controller.

I have my class that extends the UINavigationCOntroller. I cleaned everything and am just runnig the following code on the viewDidAppear.

```
navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Carpool"

    let languagesSpinner = UIBarButtonItem(title: "PT", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didClickLanguagesButton))                
    navigationItem.setRightBarButton(languagesSpinner, animated: true)
```

The title is seted up but not the button.

The strange thing is that, the item is setted up when i debug with po.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `title` with `navigationBar.topItem` and setting `rightBarButton` with `navigationItem` so try setting `rightBarButton` also with `navigationBar.topItem` .

**Try once**

```
navigationBar.topItem?.setRightBarButton(languagesSpinner, animated: true)
```

**Instead of**

```
navigationItem.setRightBarButton(languagesSpinner, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to study how UINavigationController works. Why cant i override the Navigation item ?

Comment: @DiogoAleixo Welcome mate :) Don't know about `navigationItem` overriding but may be `navigationItem` will be different in your each controller where as `navigationController` will stay same